# BooleanIndexing.replaceWhere Not Working Based On Type

Tags: nd4j

I started working with ND4j recently and came upon an issue I don't have an explanation for.

```
INDArray test =
        Nd4j.create(new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0}, new long[] {2, 2}, DataType.UINT16);
BooleanIndexing.replaceWhere(test, 0.0, Conditions.greaterThan(0)); // test not updated

INDArray testCasted = test.castTo(DataType.FLOAT);
BooleanIndexing.replaceWhere(testCasted, 0.0, Conditions.greaterThan(0)); // testCasted is updated
```

In the code above, an array created with `UINT16` datatype doesn't get updated by the `replaceWhere` function. But when the array is casted to a `FLOAT`, `replaceWhere` works as expected. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

For now just use cast. Please feel free to file an issue and we'll take a look at that at: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues - it's likely just us forgetting to auto update some of the types. Thanks!

Comment: I will file an issue. I was certain I was doing something wrong haha.